# how to replace the single quotation with // in excel macros using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a string in sheet 2, and the string starts with " ' " single quotation, I want to replace the  single quotation with //, I have written the following code through excel macro, however the output starts with ' as well as // and then the string

```
Sub Conversion()

Dim qtpval, selval
qtpval = "'"
selval = "//"
'qtpval = Sheets("Variables").Range("A2")
'qtpval = Left(qtpval, Len(qtpval) - 1)
'MsgBox qtpval
'selval = Sheets("Variables").Range("B2")
'MsgBox selval

MoveCode qtpval, selval

'readvariables

End Sub

Function MoveCode(qtpval, selval)

Dim lRowCount As Long

Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
lRowCount = Worksheets("QTP Code").UsedRange.Rows.Count
'MsgBox lRowCount

Dim i
Dim j
j = 1

For i = 1 To lRowCount

tempvar = Sheets("QTP Code").Range("A" & i)
chngval = Replace(tempvar, qtpval, selval)
'If InStr(tempvar, "'") Then
'MsgBox "pass"

'Sheets(3).Range("A" & j).Value = "//" & tempvar
Sheets(3).Range("A" & j).Value = chngval
j = j + 1
'End If

Next i

End Function

'Function readvariables()

'Dim varRowCount As Long

'Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
'varRowCount = Worksheets("Variables").UsedRange.Rows.Count
'MsgBox varRowCount

'End Function
```

Comment: Can you show us the code/string that you're converting? It doesn't make much sense without an example

Comment: I suspect the leading apostrophe is not part of the cell's value but the `PrefixCharacter`, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194949.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the the single quote is a **PreFixCharacter** that does not appear in the cell, but only controls formats.  For example if you enter:

```
'A
```

in a cell you will get:

[image]

The quote appears in the Formula Bar, but not in the cell.  In fact if you examine the length of **A1** it will be only **1**

Because the single quote is not really there, *Replace()* can't remove it.  Instead consider:

```
Sub DontQuoteMe()
    Dim s As String, r As Range

    Set r = Range("A1")
    s = r.Value
    MsgBox Len(s) & vbCrLf & s

    If r.PrefixCharacter = "'" Then
        r.Value = "//" & r.Value
    End If

End Sub
```

This will

- locate cells with the PreFixCharacter
- pre-append the slashes
- remove the PreFixCharacter

---

**EDIT#1:**

This macro will loop over the cells and fix those that have the PreFixCharacter:

```
Sub QuoteKleaner()
    Dim s As String, r As Range
    Dim rBig As Range

    Set rBig = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    For Each r In rBig
        If r.PrefixCharacter = "'" Then
            r.Value = "//" & r.Value
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Gary, i have multiple cells in my excel sheet, can you please give me code with a for loop.

Comment: @SrikanthChillara  See my **EDIT#1:**